Sources of a subset contained in each other then the subsets are contained in each other
True or false…
if $f: A\rightarrow B,\ \ D_1,D_2\ \subseteq \ B, \mbox{and}\ f^{-1}[D_1] \subseteq f^{-1}[D_2]$,
then
$ D_1 \subseteq D_2$?
It seems like the answer is false because if there are images in $B$ that have no matching source in $A$, then we could say that the "source" of these images is the empty set, then it would be possible that the claim is true while $D_1$ is not a subset of $D_2$ (the empty set is contained in any set).
Does it make sense? Am I in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Yes you are! Now construct a small concrete counterexample.

A = {1,2,3}
B = {1,2,3}
D1 = {1}
D2 = {2,3}
$f^{-1}[D1]$ = {}
$f^{-1}[D2]$ = {1,2,3}
That way, D1 is not a subset of D2, while the sources of D1 are a subset of D2.

Fine! (you forgot to define $f$ but I found two ways to define it accordingly). I think you could post a self-answer with this example, or even a smaller one, like $A=D_2=\varnothing$, $B=D_1={a}$, $f=$ empty map.
